# TeamCity nuget pack step missing files when packaged

Tags: nuget, teamcity

Our first step is a MsBuild for our .sln file. We pass in our platform and config and everything is built correctly.

Next we want to NuGet pack all the files for Octopus Deploy to use. In this step we specify all of our .csproj files (not sure why, everything is already built)

The package that is created contains 2 folders, Content which contains all the files needed minus bin and the Lib folder which contains only the projects compiled dlls. It's not including any of the other dlls referenced in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it might be easier for you to use Octopack to handle the creation of the NuGet packages to be deployed.

**Step 1**. Install the [Octopack NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OctoPack/) into the projects that are your deployable applications.

```
Install-Package OctoPack
```

**Step 2**. Ensure you have a build step before the main compilation that will install any referenced NuGet packages.

[image]

**Step 3**. Install the [TeamCity plugin for Octopus deploy](https://octopus.com/downloads) from the downloads page and restart the TeamCity server service

**Step 4**. You'll now see additional options in your MSBuild runner configuration and if you check the following box in your build configurations, it will produce a NuGet package for you which should have everything required for a successful deployment.

[image]

**As a small tip**, I publish the package straight to Octopus by referencing the output package (rather than waiting for it to be attached as an artifact at the end of the build and thus requiring two build configurations)

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see how it works. It also looks like none of the dlls from external references are being included in my package. I.e. AutoFac, net framework, EF, etc. Will this also include those?

Comment: If they are referenced as NuGet packages then the installer step should restore them prior to the build. If they aren't standard package references then they may need to be under source control (not advisable)

Comment: What is best practice to handle those types of non-NuGet references in an automated way?

Comment: It is to put them under source control, so you ensure they exist on the build agent at the point of compilation.

Comment: We do have a "packages" folder under source control that contains all of our ext libraries, but those don't get included in the package

Comment: OctoPack is just a wrapper around NuGet packaging. I don't think it will help you with your problem at all.

Comment: Running nuget against a project file won't include referenced packages without some hoops (custom nuspec etc) and the packaged application won't be in the optimal format for deployment using Octopus Deploy (e.g. A web app needs the dlls in the bin directory). Octopack will do all of that for you with no effort - OctoPack will automatically package all of the files in the build output directory for the project. http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Using+OctoPack

Answer (score -1):

If NuGet pack is not packaging your application as you expected from your project file, you have to create a NuGet spec file and specify how things should be packaged. For a web application that is as simple as creating a simple .spec file and putting it into your web application directory, but for other projects that can be a little more complicated. Check out the Nuspec Reference to see how to add your content and dependencies. https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference

Comment: Would the .nuspec have to be manually updated every time we add or remove files to the project?

Comment: No, but it might have to be updated if you require new dependencies. The spec file gives you full control over what and how it's packaged. Nuget can also create the package directly from your project file but in your case that's not working like you want it to.